# PostgreSQL schema designer

Tags: postgresql, schema

I am looking for a program to build a schema from the newly created database PostgreSQL, preferably with a beautiful design schemes, such as a MySQL Workbench, or change styles schemes.

What can you tell? Thank you!

Comment: GenMyModel (https://www.genmymodel.com) is now supporting online database design.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that [`WWWSQLDesigner`](http://code.google.com/p/wwwsqldesigner/) can do it for you. There's a demo [`here`](http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/). You'll need to download it and install it on a local server.

Answer (score 1):

These three are free and quite good:

- pgDesigner: http://pgdesigner.sourceforge.net/en/index.html
- SQL PowerArchitect: http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect (download without registration from: http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/)
- OpenModelSphere http://www.modelsphere.org